# Avoiding Multiple Copies of the IIFE Pattern

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, npm, gulp, iife

I have seen the following IIFE pattern (Does it have a name?), which according to [this](http://toddmotto.com/what-function-window-document-undefined-iife-really-means/) blog post protects against other plugins, improves minification and has a **tiny** performance benefit. I also personally added a namespace to the IIFE:

```
(function (MyNamespace, $, window, document, undefined) {
    "use strict";

    // My Code

})(window.MyNamespace = window.MyNamespace || {}, window.jQuery, window, document);
```

I have seen this pattern used in every JavaScript file. What about after concatenation and minification? How can I ensure that my code is wrapped with only **one** of the above IIFE's? Do tools like NPM, Gulp/Grunt help in this regard? Is there a standard way of handling this scenario?

Comment: The performance impact of this is minimal, what problem are you having due to multiple uses of the pattern?

Comment: It's code you have to duplicate in every file. After concatenation and minification, you only need one copy of it which would further help with minification. This seems to be a fairly common pattern, I had hoped someone had solved this problem.

Comment: At what state are you running you build tool? on watch or more as a final step?

Comment: If you're using a build tool, use that to surround your files (that don't have this block of code in) in a single copy of it.  [Knockout for example](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/master/build/fragments/extern-pre.js) does this.

Comment: Thanks @JamesThorpe for the example. I also happened to watch Paul Irish video on [jQuery](http://www.paulirish.com/2010/10-things-i-learned-from-the-jquery-source/) and discovered that they take a similar approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some investigation, library writers like jQuery and knockout handle this by pre-pending and appending the IFFE to the JavaScript. They then have a make file which concatenates everything together.

The start of the jQuery IIFE is a lot more complicated to handle non-browser scenarios.

**[jQuery intro.js](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/intro.js)**

```
(function( global, factory ) {
    if ( typeof module === "object" && typeof module.exports === "object" ) {
        module.exports = global.document ?
            factory( global, true ) :
            function( w ) {
                if ( !w.document ) {
                    throw new Error( "jQuery requires a window with a document" );
                }
                return factory( w );
            };
    } else {
        factory( global );
    }
}(typeof window !== "undefined" ? window : this, function( window, noGlobal ) {
```

**[jQuery outro.js](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/outro.js)**

```
return jQuery;
}));
```

Knockout (Thanks to @JamesThorpe) takes a slightly different approach to resolving the window and it's descendants.

**[Knockout extern-pre.js](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/master/build/fragments/extern-pre.js)**

```
(function(undefined){
    var window = this || (0, eval)('this'),
        document = window['document'],
        navigator = window['navigator'],
        jQueryInstance = window["jQuery"],
        JSON = window["JSON"];
```

**[Knockout extern-post.js](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/master/build/fragments/extern-post.js)**

```
}());
```

You can then use something like [gulp-concat](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-concat) to sandwich the intro and outro files around your own script files.